# Which kind of javascript errors stop further code execution of the web application

Tags: javascript, html

I am from java background. I often see so many javascript errors in the console in my web application. However, not everytime further code execution gets impacted by those errors and I see application running properly. Could someone explain me whether every javascript error effects further code execution or only any specific type of errors do that. Thank you.

Comment: js also have try/catch so some errors may be handled even if they logged into console

Comment: You mean if we don't handle error using try/catch, that should stop further code execution all the time? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but that error will not affect other js code. If you have 2 different buttons with click handlers and one fails, it doesn't mean code from another button will stop working forever (until page reload). Or even that same button will stop working. You can click it again and it either will fail again or may run smoothly next time if conditions changed.

Comment: You mean the scope of the impact of an error would be only within the function of with in that flow of code in a file but not?

Comment: Yes, it's only will affect current scope. If it's some isolated function, all further execution will fail inside that function. If it's some function inside other function, all further execution will fail up to the top of the call stack (or if `catch` met). If it's in global scope inside <script> tag, I guess all execution inside that <script> tag would fail, but it shouldn't affect other <script> tags (either it's a code inside html file or link to external file). However I'm not sure about my latter assumption. Maybe someone can cover it in more details in answer.